# Crear migraciones con foreign key cuando el ID es un string en laravel

Tags: laravel, migracion, foranea

tengo una tabla intermedia donde en lugar de utilizar el clásico bigInteger y luego crear la llave foránea, utilizaré un ID que estoy recuperando de una API, dicho ID será con el que voy a trabajar ya que los ID de mi base de datos estarán moviéndose constantemente (son sincronizaciones que moverán bastante la tabla eliminando y añadiendo nuevos datos a la tabla)
la tabla intermedia será llenada desde una API que tiene los ID como string, ya que tiene letras

esta es la migración

```
    Schema::table('customer_franchise', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('customer_salesforce_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('customer_salesforce_id')->references('salesforce_id')->on('customers')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('franchise_salesforce_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('franchise_salesforce_id')->references('salesforce_id')->on('franchises')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('salesforce_updated_date')->nullable();
    });
```

el problema es que cuando intento ejecutar la migración, obtengo lo siguiente:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'unsigned not
> null, add `franchise_salesforce_id` varchar(255) unsigned not null,'
> at line 1 (SQL: alter table `customer_franchise` add
> `customer_salesforce_id` varchar(255) unsigned not null, add
> `franchise_salesforce_id` varchar(255) unsigned not null, add
> `created_at` timestamp null, add `updated_at` timestamp null, add
> `salesforce_updated_date` varchar(255) null)

cómo se hace para crear una llave foránea de un ID que será string?

Comment: `unsigned` no se puede usar con un tipo de dato varchar, prueba con `index` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#available-index-types

Comment: Buen día, puedes mostrar también tus otra migraciones?